# Drawing bar scale with units

Tags: qml

I want to create a bar scale with units in Qt.

Is Qml has any component of the similar type that  meets my above requirement?

Just for info: My QtQuick version is 1.0

Comment: If you need a commercial version you can look at this link http://qt.digia.com/Product/Qt-Add-Ons/Charts/. Digia offers a commercial chart Add-on for sophisticated graph operations. If you need a open source version, there are already suggestions available in SO, http://qt.digia.com/Product/Qt-Add-Ons/Charts/.

Comment: I want to dynamically draw the scale units and their interval. Do you have any link to do this?...something a kind of a ruler

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Qt Quick Colibri](http://projects.developer.nokia.com/colibri).

It contains a lot of QML plugins, including [CLHistogram](https://projects.forum.nokia.com/colibri/wiki/CLHistogram) that should fit your needs.

Comment: I want to dynamically draw the scale units and their interval. Do you have any link to do this?